# Mouse over events with JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I'm trying to create a custom mouse over event on a JButton. The reason being that my JButton is currently an image, so I had to remove all the borders and animations and what not. so I did this:

```
btnSinglePlayer.setOpaque(false);
btnSinglePlayer.setContentAreaFilled(false);
btnSinglePlayer.setBorderPainted(false);
```

And that works perfect to only display the image, and the button does in fact work. I want to know if there's any pre-built methods perhaps that can do this, or how I would go about learning to do what I want.

More specifically, what I want the image to do when I mouse over is for it to get just a bit bigger.

I have tried these so far, and did nothing:

```
btnSinglePlayer.setRolloverIcon(singlePlayerButton);
btnSinglePlayer.setPressedIcon(singlePlayerButton);
```

Comment: True setting rollOverEnabled to true. You might also like to look at setRolloverSelectedIcon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. for [Icon to use implemented methods in API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7919280/714968)
2. you can to use [ButtonModel with ChangeListener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5755124/714968)
3. (by default) for [JButtons JComponents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) there no reason to use `Mouse(Xxx)Listener` or its `MouseEvent`, all those events are implemented and correctly

Comment: Oh man I can't believe I didn't see that. See whenever I was doing the setRollOver, I was setting the image to the same exact image. Thanks man, number 1 really helped.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative You can achieve this by registering `MouseListener` to the `JButton` and override `mouseEntered()` ,`mouseExited()` , `mousePressed()` and `mouseReleased()` method.For Example:

```
        final ImageIcon icon1 = new ImageIcon("tray.gif");
        final JButton button = new JButton(icon1);
        final int width = icon1.getIconWidth();
        final int height = icon1.getIconHeight();
        button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
        {
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent evt)
            {
                icon1.setImage((icon1.getImage().getScaledInstance(width + 10, height,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
                //button.setIcon(icon1);
            }
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent evt)
            {
                icon1.setImage((icon1.getImage().getScaledInstance(width , height,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
            }
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt)
            {
                icon1.setImage((icon1.getImage().getScaledInstance(width + 5, height,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
            }
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent evt)
            {
                icon1.setImage((icon1.getImage().getScaledInstance(width + 10, height,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
            }
        });
        button.setOpaque(false);
        button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        button.setBorderPainted(false);
```