# Jbutton with an image as background can't be clicked

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, imageicon

I'm doing a menu in Java and I'm using images as `JButtons`. However, when I run the application I can't click on the buttons. Here's the code of a button:

```
JButton butoEtnies = null;
try {
    butoEtnies = new JButton(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("imatges/Etnies.png"))));
} catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
butoEtnies.setContentAreaFilled(false);
butoEtnies.setBorderPainted(false);
butoEtnies.setFocusPainted(false);
butoEtnies.addActionListener(this);
```

And here is the actionPerformed:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String et = null;
    String accio = e.getActionCommand();

    if(accio.equals("Etnies"))
        et = entrarEtnies();
    else
        System.exit(0);
}
```

Can it be that it doesn't recognise "Etnies" in the actionPerformed method? The problem gets fixed if I use: `JButton butoEtnies = new JButton("Etnies");` But then it shows 2 buttons, the one with the image and another one with this text. If I press the one with the text it works but I still can't click the other one.
How can I do it?

Comment: I'm don't believe, for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE short runnable, compilable for Icon to use [private Icon infoIcon =  UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.informationIcon");](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7919280/714968)

Comment: I didn't understand a single thing you said haha

Comment: haha then to see detailed comment as an answer, this is SSCCE/MCVE, did you understand this single thing, short, runnable, compilable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have either given it a title, or an image, not both.
You should use the

```
JButton butoEtnies = new JButton("Etnies", /*Here goes the icon*/);
```

Or you can also try:

```
JButton butoEtnies = new JButton("Etnies");
butoEtnies.setIcon(/*Here goes the icon*/);
```

Besides, [here's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html#JButton%28java.lang.String,%20javax.swing.Icon%29) the Java API for JButton

EDIT #2

Next, provides an particular actionlistener for the butoEtnies button, in which you do not need to specify an ID or a title for the getActionCommand

```
JButton butoEtnies = new JButton (/*path to icon*/);
butoEtnies.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
         //You can code whatever you want here
         System.out.println("butoEtnies clicked");
     }
});
```

Comment: The first option is what I'm looking for, but it shows like this:
http://i.imgur.com/iwI0BBN.png. I can click both, but how can I make the text on the right dissapear?

Comment: Then, it means that your button already comes with the text, and the JButton tries to append it somewhere.

Comment: How can I avoid this?

Comment: Do not set any title to the button. And follow EDIT #2 for a precise actionlistener